# Adding Menu Items in Custom Post Types

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm creating a directory of restaurants with Custom Post Types.  Each restaurant's information has its own post.  I would like to be able to add the restaurant's menu items to each custom post type and I'm curious how I would achieve this.

I would need to make a number of fields which contain information about each menu item - the name, price, and description.  I would also need the ability to click a button that says "Add another" which would then produce another row of these fields so the user can add another menu item.

I'd be very appreciative if anybody knew how to do this or had a link to a tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this tutorial- Adding Custom Fields to a Custom Post Type, the Right Way, it may help you out :)

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/adding-custom-fields-to-a-custom-post-type-the-right-way